# PHP wildcard in domain suffix using server variable?

Tags: php, regex, cross-domain, host

I'm using the PHP server variable to check if a domain is true and then do something. My issue is that other developers will have the same site locally for development / Git but they might name it with a different domain suffix such as `.dev`, `.local` or `.whatever`.

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if($host == "subdomain1.example.com" or $host == "subdomain1.example.dev") {

 // do something!

}
```

The rest of the URL stays the same for everyone. I can see that this might end up being too verbose if we have to account for every local domian suffix a dev uses so instead of lots of `"or"` syntax, it would be nice to somehow use a wildcard with something like this psuedocode below:

```
 $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    if($host == "subdomain1.example.*") {

     // do something!

    }
```

... but I am guessing I need to use regex. I googled around and could not really find much. My regex-foo is pretty lacking as well since I am a themer / front end dev.

Comment: To train regex skill, I recommend site http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If beginning is always the same, use `strpos()`

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'subdomain.example.') === 0) {
    // do something
}
```

If zone differs, use regex

```
if (preg_match('/.+\.example\.(org|com|dev)$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: This works really well, the first one is actually what I ended up using and then I do an `elseif` for a different subdomain. Thanks.